# Dotnetnuke HTML module: add dynamic style

Tags: html, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I've a small question about styling in the HTML module.
Can I add a specific style to every 'li' of 'a' element that is written in the text box? More specific, can I specify a specific classname for every 'li' element that is used in that specific module?

Thanks!

[Image of dnn html module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiMIY.png)

Comment: Yes you can. If you need more specific answer, ask more specific questions including simplified version of your code

Comment: At this moment I do not have a code example... Is it possible to give an example of how to assign a css class to a li or anchor element?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the intended usage of Stackoverflow. You may search the web for those examples

Comment: I've added a picture of my html module.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to necessarily apply a style to "ALL" of those elements, but you can customize the available styles to have options when the user tries the "Select Style" option.

The [CKEditor documentation](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Add-Style-Unordered-List) shows this.